# How to show that a list of sets with the parameters (4,2,1) is A VALID BLOCK DESIGN?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, combinatorial-designs

I have to determine whether  or not the list of sets with the parameters v=4, b=6, r=3, k=2 and $\lambda$ = 1 is a valid block design. Now my first thought was to ensure that these parameters satisfy the conditions:

1. b $\geq$ v
2. bk = vr
3. $\lambda$ (v-1) = r (k-1).

And they did satisfy the conditions. However this is not sufficient according to my lecturer to show its a valid block design. So my next step was to identify the design as an affine plane of order n=2 and since an affine plane is a symmetry block design then the list of sets do form a valid block design. However, I am not  sure if this is enough either. Can someone help me out please?

Comment: There is no "the list of sets" with these parameters. Are you asked to determine, instead, *whether there exists some* block design with these parameters?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry my terminology is poor but this is essentially what I have to do. We were given some blocks of varieties which resulted in these parameters so that's why I stated the question as such. I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is not sufficient** to check that these parameters satisfy the equations you've listed. These equations are necessary conditions: if the parameters violate them, then there can be no block design. But they do not guarantee that there do exist block designs with a set of parameters.

**It is sufficient** to invoke the affine plane of order two. To be precise, what you are saying here is "Yes, a block design with these parameters does exist. The affine plane of order $2$ is an example."

**The best answer** would often be to say this, and also list what the points and blocks of the affine plane of order $2$ are. These parameters are very small, and it can be easily checked by hand that the set system with $v=4$ points $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and $b=6$ blocks $$\{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{1,4\}, \{2,3\}, \{2,4\}, \{3,4\}$$ is a block design with the parameters we wanted. Additionally, you don't have to think of this block design as an affine plane; it is also the block design obtained by taking all $2$-element subsets of the set of points.

(That's a less interesting but also valid family of block designs, giving a $b = \binom v2$, $r=v-1$, $k=2$, $\lambda=1$ block design for any $v$.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you also assist me with one more question. I also have to show that if i have b sets of Ai s (where the Ai s form the sets of a finite projective plane) then each Ai includes exactly one element of A1. Now my general idea was to use say that if each Ai did not include one element from A1 then the parameters of the projective plane won't be met since there wont be pairs of the elements in A1 with other elements in the design.

Comment: The answer to that depends a lot on context - what you've already shown about the projective plane. If you already know that a projective plane is a block design with $\lambda=1$, then you know almost immediately that each $A_i$ can include at most one element of $A_1$, if $i\ne 1$. If you know that a projective plane is a *symmetric* block design, this tells you that $|A_1 \cap A_i|$ is *exactly* $1$ for each $i\ne 1$. If you don't know these things, you'll have to prove them from properties of the projective plane that you do know.